# Jquery get all ... inside this or $(this)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, this

how can i get for example all links inside a all ready selected jquery element (this)

```
$("#container li").each(function(){
   $("this a").each(function(){
      // links inside this li element
   });
});
```

This does not work is there a other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function:

```
$('#container li').each(function() {
    $(this).find('a').each(function() {
        // links inside this li element
    });
});
```

or to avoid nested loops you could directly select the links and then fetch the parent `li` if needed:

```
$('#container li a').each(function() {
    var parentLi = $(this).parent('li');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively to Darin's proposal, jQuery allows you to define a context node for a selector.

So, you could do this:

```
var
  $listItems = $('#container li'),
  // use $listItems as context
  $anchors = $('a', $listItems);
```

Comment: Or, a [ **little more directly** ](http://jsfiddle.net/b9S4p/): `$('a', '#container li')`

Comment: Sure, though as I understood it, this was about reusing elements. Your version seems to defeat the purpose entirely.